# Creating user profile with target audience using SQL Database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a user specific access in my sharepoint application.

i have to pick up the value from the external database.

e.g. i have the external  database having fields domainid, emailId,....... and accessControlValue.

i want to create the target audience based on accessControlValue.

the accessControlValue has values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

please suggest how can i acomplish the goal.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. What is the connection between the value in accessControlValue and the user access?

Comment: I want to create the audience depending on accessControlValue. e.g. if accessControlVAlue is 0 then that person can only view the site. if accessControlVAlue  is 9 then that person can perform the administrative task. like that for the other accessContro value.